# Using Grafana with BigQuery data source

Tags: graph, charts, google-bigquery, grafana, diagram

I am trying to graph some bigquery time series data, is there an easy way to do it with something like grafana?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To visualize BigQuery data with Grafana, you can use the open source datasource plugin available from https://github.com/doitintl/bigquery-grafana

Here is how it looks:

[image]

You can either use Query Builder or plain BigQuery query to visualize your data. Both time series and table modes are supported along with annotations and sharded tables.

Answer (score 3):

> is there an easy way to do it **with something like** grafana

Data Studio has rich support for time-series - you should check [Visualizing BigQuery data using Data Studio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio) to start with it.

For more details - see [Time series in Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697?hl=en#time-series-in-data-studio)

Note: there is a mentioning there of `You can show up to 5 metrics in your time series chart` - I do believe they now support up to `10 metrics`! to produce something like below

[image]

Comment: Datastudio has some severe limitations when it comes to timeseries data, the smallest unit it can handle is hours (YYYYMMDDHH)

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022:**

Now there is a BigQuery Plugin by Grafana Labs themselves: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-bigquery-datasource/

Worth mentioning it was forked from the initial Plugin by DoiT International. However, it was substantially improved by Grafana Labs.